# How can I get the sipdroid project on my workspace to edit it with its library?

Tags: android, video, call, sip, voip

I downloaded this  open source project from  https://github.com/mconf/sipdroid but when I run it, it show to me:

```
Android library projects cannot be launched.
```

Please, is there someone who can help me, It was my first time to download an open source project.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do following steps :
1. In the Package Explorer, right-click the sipdroid project and select Properties.
2. In the Properties window, select the "Android" properties group at left and locate the Library properties at right.
3. Un-Select the "is Library" checkbox and click Apply.
4. Click OK to close the Properties window.
5. Then run project.